# Mongoose Version Errors: connecting to the mongdb

Tags: node.js, mongoose

I just cannot connect the `mongdb` correctly and I had tried many answers to fix it.

I used the latest version of mongoose and the code as following:

```html
mongoose.connect('mongodb://localhost/photo_app', {useMongoClient: true});
```

Add the `useMongoClient` option no warning and error but also no response.

I tried to uninstall it and install the 4.10.8 version no warning but it report the following codes again.

```html
MongoError: failed to connect to server [localhost:27017] on first connect [MongoError: connect ECONNREFUSED 127.0.0.1:27017]
```

So there are other conclusions for my question? Thanks!

Comment: Is mongo running? The connection refused suggests that you don't have mongo running locally on port 27017

Comment: @Aky_0788 not at all related